# Java watch service not working in linux does not work for the files modified by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write java program to track the list of files modified by eclipse in real time. I have written watcher program using java watcher service. 
However no notification is received by service if the file is edited by eclipse.

Following is the code I am using :

```java
public class AutoFormatter {

    private static final Integer TAB_TO_SPACE = 4;

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        if (Objects.isNull(args) || args.length < 2) {
            printUsage();
        }

        String pathToWatch = args[0];
        String extensionToWatch = args[1];
        System.out.println("Watching path : " + pathToWatch + " for " + extensionToWatch + " files");

        Path watchPath = Paths.get(pathToWatch);

        try {
            watchPath.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

            while (true) {

                WatchKey modifiedKey = watcher.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : modifiedKey.pollEvents()) {
                    System.out.println("event.kind():" + event.kind());
                    if (event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                        Path modifiedPath = ev.context();
                        System.out.println("Caught event : " + modifiedPath.toString());
                        if (modifiedPath.toString().endsWith(extensionToWatch)) {
                            System.out.println("Formatting..." + modifiedPath.toString());
                            Formatter.run(modifiedPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath(), TAB_TO_SPACE);
                            System.out.println("Formatting completed... for " + modifiedPath.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!modifiedKey.reset())
                    break;

            }

        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }

    private static void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("java TestWatchService /tmp txt - To watch text files being updated in /tmp file");

    }
}
```

Comment: you can try `File#lastModified()` instead

Comment: Maybe try and watch for `OVERFLOW` events?

Comment: Note that Eclipse provides extensive support for telling plug-ins about changes to resources.

Comment: @Mena OVERFLOW doesn't help either.

Comment: @greg-449 yes but just curious as of why eclipse is an exception. Tried other tools like gedit/vi and the events are received properly.

Comment: @user151784 you mean you do not have overflow events?

Comment: @mena, no even capturing OVERFLOW events doesn't get the notification when the file is modified by eclipse. (I think OVERFLOW events are captured by default in WatchService).

Comment: @user151784 if memory serves you should register for overflow events. My point was that *maybe*, for some unknown reason, your eclipse-based changes might have been all dumped to overflow events... which wouldn't resolve anything per se, but maybe shed some additional light.

Comment: @Mena Yes, I took the suggestion and did the change, tried and tested. But that didn't work.

Comment: @ChotaBheem ah ok. Not quite sure then :(

Comment: Eclipse doesn't do anything special, it just uses the normal file I/O APIs.

Comment: `If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on remote systems be detected.`  So is your workspace on a network drive by chance?

Comment: @geert3 yes, that's correct. My files are located on remote system. But still the when I edit the same with with vi/gedit, watchservice(java) does notify with ENTRY_MODIFY. It's only edit via eclipse doesn't work.